# Latex Bibliography Reference Going Off The Page

Tags: latex, biblatex

I have the following reference in my bibliography and the URL is going off of the side of the page. I am using the following package and need it on the page for printing margin guidlines:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

Here is one of the offending references. I have tried a `\\` but these end up as `%5C` in the URL. Please help.

```
@online{atlantichamburger,
    author    = "Libby Bawcombe",
    year      = "2014",
    title     = "The Hamburger Menu-Icon Debate",
    location  = "Washington",
    publisher = "The Atlantic",
    url       = "https://www.theatlantic.com/product/archive/2014/08/the-hamburger-menu-debate/379145/"
}
```

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344711/178895

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix this using the following link:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134191/line-breaks-of-long-urls-in-biblatex-bibliography

Essentially, you need to add:

```
\usepackage{url}

%%% --- The following two lines are what needs to be added --- %%%
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the url package and mention the URL using `howpublished`

```
howpublished = {\url{https://www.theatlantic.com/product/archive/2014/08/the-hamburger-menu-debate/379145/}}
```

Untested - based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/long-urls-in-bibliography) in TeX SE.

Edit: fixed syntactical error and changed `url` item to `howpublished` as shown [here](https://nschloe.blogspot.com/2009/06/bibtex-how-to-cite-website_21.html).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I get a syntax error. However the link and package helped me come up with a solution.